# Removing app from task manager kills Broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, taskmanager

I'm creating an app which detects Power Key press (both in foreground and background). I'm using the following BroadcastReceiver for this

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String action = arg1.getAction();

    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
            || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "DETECTED", 5000).show();
    }
}
```

I'm starting the broadcast from my MainActivity

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Receive.class);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

This works fine in both foreground and background, but when I swipe away my app from Task manager, it won't detect it any more. Also, this works in other phones.

I thought it might be a case with my phone only, but I've an app in my mobile which detects the power key press even on removing it from Task manager (So, it's also possible in my phone)

Comment: May be that application's Receiver is registered in manifest file. And its not inner class of activity. Where have you registered receiver? in manifest or using `registerReceiver`?

Comment: I've used registerReceiver in MainActivity before using sendBroadcast method

Answer (score 0):

You have to define all the action in manifest file. Why it is needed because Android system maintains list of intent-filters at the time of installation of application. You should use staic intent-filter when you want to hanldle broadcast even if application is not in running state.

You have use dynamin intent-filter registering. This should be used only when you want to handle broadcast when application is in running state.

Comment: I've also tried defining the action in manifest as you said. But the same result, doesn't Toast on cleaning app from task manager

Comment: Can you try with adding priority in receiver tag as 999 .It might help you in receiving broadcast

Comment: Can you try to use application context, instead of receiver context. Please put logger also with toast. What i am realising is that toast will be associated with Activity and as there are no activity when application swap from recent application list, task are not visible to you.

Comment: I tried with application context in place of receiver context and also added Log. But the thing is that, I can see the log when application is running, but as soon as I remove it from Task manager, all the log gets disappeared.

Its getting very much annoying now. Putting so much of efforts from the past couple of days but not a single thing is working out